# Error of "In if (x == 1) { ... : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to calculate the mean and sd of certain columns in a data.frame. I run the following loop:

```
calculations <- by(dataset, dataset$id, function (x) 
{
  if(x == 1) 
  {
    c(mean(x$Var1),mean(x$Var2))
    print("Cannot take sd, number of obs is equal to 1")
  }
  else(x > 1)
  {
    c(mean(x$Var1), mean(x$Var2), sd(x$Var1), sd(x$Var2))
  }
  #return(c(mean(x$Var1), mean(x$Var2), sd(x$Var1), sd(x$Var2))) 
})
```

and I get an output of:

```
dataset$id: 1
[1] 0.3961182 3.8605641 1.0251303 2.6779033
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 2
[1] 0.1656521 3.7565732 0.8687900 2.2305298
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 3
[1] -0.3831954  4.0803145  1.3875692  2.1146944
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 4
[1] 0.6719857 4.7523648 0.2001029 1.3715562
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 5
[1] 0.01666328 3.18141270 0.98473329 1.76379804
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 6
[1] 0.2542346 4.6464406 1.1077001 2.4604031
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dataset$id: 7
[1] -0.1826018  5.6737908         NA         NA
```

up to dataset$id 40. with my loop I want the NA's to print off "Cannot take sd." When I run my code I just end up with the following error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (x == 1) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (x == 1) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (x == 1) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to test if `x` has more than 1 row, not if `x` equals 1. Try `if(nrow(x) == 1)` and `else(nrow(x)>1)`. The variable `x` is a data.frame, it doesn't make a lot of sense to directly compare it to a numeric constant.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from

```
by(dataset, dataset$id, function (x) ....
```

that `x` takes subsets of rows of `datatset`. Your code then says

```
if (x == 1)
```

and as `x` is a data frame what do you hope to achieve by testing if the data frame is equal to 1?

If you are testing for the number of rows then consider

```
if (nrow(x) > 1L)
```

as the test and flip the content of the `if` and `else` branches or do

```
if (nrow(x) < 2L) ## or
if (nrow(x) == 1L)
```

if you don't want to flip the branches.